# Change next order number (post_id) woocommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to change the sequence of next new order number ( post_id ) in woocommerce because of some number conflicts with our accounting software who is integrated with woocommerce.

Our latest order number is 51249 and i want the next and newer to start with 70000.

Is it safe to run following sql query?:
`ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT = 70000;`

Comment: Can the software read a custom order field, or the order_id is definitely a requirement?

Comment: Unfortunately, only the post id. And I cannot modify the integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has the solution.

Yes, **it is safe to increase** `AUTO_INCREMENT` as long as you are sure you can never go back. The opposite (reducing) is not as easy and safe as increasing it. I would recommend you check the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value just in case before running the query.

In conclusion, this is the correct answer to achieve what you asked. Remember making a backup before just in case.

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT = 70000;
```